# Django: Queries and calculations inside CreateView

Tags: python, django, calculation, create-view

I am relatively new to Django, so I am not sure if what I am asking possible.

I am building a website with functionality to rate users and write reviews about them. I have model for users (that has average rating field) and a model for reviews (with fields of `author`, `user_profile`, `grade` and `review`). I am using `CreateView` for making reviews.

I am trying to do the following:

1. To make query to get all previous grades of that person (from `Reviews` model).
2. Make calculations (sum all previous grades, add the new one and all that divide by number of grades (including new grade))
3. Save new average grade to `UserProfile` model
4. Save review to `Reviews` model
5. Redirect user to current detail view

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    avg_grade = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Reviews(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    review = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

In `views.py` I managed to make query of grades of that user, but not sure where to do calculations for new average grade (if this is possible inside a Class-Based-View):

```
class CreateReview(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = Forma_recenzije
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detail')
    template_name = 'accounts/recenzija.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(id=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return Reviews.objects.filter(user_profile=u)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return super(CreateReview, self).form_valid(form)
```

urlpatterns:

```
[...
    url(r'^dadilje/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.DadiljaDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r'^dadilje/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/recenzija$', views. CreateReview.as_view(), name="recenzije")
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the new average once you have called `super()`, before you return the response.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
    form.instance.user_profile = user_profile`
    response = super(CreateReview, self).form_valid(form)
    avg_grade = Review.objects.filter(user_profile=user_profile).aggregate(Avg('grade'))['grade__avg']
    user_profile.avg_grade = avg_grade
    user_profile.save()
    return response
```

Or, if you find that calling `super()` makes it hard to see what's going on, you could explicitly save the form and redirect instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
    form.instance.user_profile = user_profile`
    review = form.save()
    avg_grade = Review.objects.filter(user_profile=user_profile).aggregate(Avg('grade'))['grade__avg']
    user_profile.avg_grade = avg_grade
    user_profile.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Note that you may not have to store the `avg_grade` on the user profile -- you could use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) to calculate the averages when you need them.

Comment: I up voted for suggesting using annotate over creating a UserProfile model to store it. Storing that calculated value may be a premature optimization. Unless users have a very large number of reviews (hundreds of thousands+ depending on the DB specs) annotate will likely perform well enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for and it works. I had some problems making it work because I gave model and view same name.

I know about annotate approach and used it before, but now I want to be able to sort that data using order_by() method and can't use it anymore.

Comment: You *can* order on an annotated field. Yes, I would avoid using the same name for the model and view. It's recommended to use the singular for model names (e.g. `Review` instead of `Reviews` (I realise in this case that `Review` is a translation of your actual model name).

Answer (score 1):

For the kind of things you want to do Django has signals which you can listen out for.

As an example, you could have a function that listens out for when `UserProfile` has been saved which clears the cache keys related to that profile.

These functions are usually added to a `signals.py` within your apps, or in `models.py` files after you've defined your model.

Signals have to be loaded after your models, so if using a `signals.py` the way I tend to do it is in `apps.py`;

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    """App config for the members app. """
    name = 'my app'
    verbose_name = _("My App")

    def ready(self):
        """ Import signals once the app is ready """
        # pylint: disable=W0612
        import myapp.signals  # noqa
```

Here's an example of a signal receivers, `pre_save` happens just before the object is saved, so you could run your calcs at this point;

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserProfile)
def userprofile_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Calc avg score
    """
    reviews = Reviews.objects.filter(user_profile=instance).aggregate(Avg('grade'))

    instance.avg_grade = reviews['grade_avg']
```

You'd probably want your receiver on the `Review` change, but the above was an easy example!!

If you're new to django this might be a bit complex, but give this a read; https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: Thanks! I found out about Django signals when I was searching how to solve this problem. Unfortunately, this is above my knowledge level so I think of this solution. I will definitely learn more about signals and hopefully use them in my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution here is use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/)

As result you separate view and domain logic and your calculations will apply after each change (not only changes in view)

Also if your calculation will take a lot of time you may easily move this functionality in async job (e.g. [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) )

Comment: Thanks. I understand that using signals has bennefits, but for now they are above my knowledge level. I will definitely read about them and hopefully use them in my future projects.

Comment: "Now is better than never." - (c) The Zen of Python))